# Catel: Customize PleaseWaitService

Tags: catel

We use the default PleaseWaitService (WPF). 
How can we style/change the screen that is showing the progressbar and status?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any customization options for the `PleaseWaitService`. If you want a different look & feel, you can simply implement your own `IPleaseWaitService` implementation (everything in Catel is pluggable & replaceable).

Comment: Is there somewhere an example?